# CSS Styling within some Wordpress PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress code that I want to use, but I am trying to give it some styling.

```
<?php global $post;
$current_post = $post; // remember the current post

for($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++):
  $post = get_previous_post(); // this uses $post->ID
  setup_postdata($post);

  // do your stuff here    
  the_excerpt();

endfor;
$post = $current_post; // restore ?>
```

Namely where it says *//do your stuff here*, I need to add the permalink and CSS styling to the_excerpt. Currently the_excerpt pulls up thumbnails on my blog.

This is the code I use for getting 2 random thumbnails, hopefully this will give you an idea of what I want for the above code.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 2, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<div class="postgallery" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<a class="title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php
$thetitle = $post->post_title; /* or you can use get_the_title() */
$getlength = strlen($thetitle);
$thelength = 35;
echo substr($thetitle, 0, $thelength);
if ($getlength > $thelength) echo "...";
?>
</a><?php if ($options['tags']) : ?><?php endif; ?> 
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You might get a better response on our wordpress site. Flag if you want the question migrated (please don't crosspost). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the_excerpt() in a set of div tags with an id or class and that will give you the hooks you need to style the content of the excerpt via the stylesheet.